# Initializer element is not a constant

Tags: c

I have to assign a static variable a value which I am getting from a function.
I tried doing the following but I am getting initializer element is not constant.

```
int countValue()
{
return 5;
}

void MatrixZero()
{

 static int count=countValue();
 count++;
 printf("count value %d \n",count);

}


int main()
{
    MatrixZero();
    return 0;   

}
```

Comment: Try using a C++ compiler. Make sure to add "#include <stdio.h>" though. C does not allow static variables to be initialized with a non-constant.

Comment: @RichardPennington This is C and C++ is a different language. I don't think compiling a C program with a C++ compiler is a good advice.

Comment: @ouah It wasn't tagged as C when it was first posted. I was just pointing out a difference in the way C and C++ handle static initializers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because... well... the initializer of your static variable is not a constant. It must be a constant expression. Try this:

```
static int count = SOME_VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
if (count == SOME_VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE) {
    count = countValue();
}
```

to check if it has already been initialized.

Answer (score 7):

A variable declared with the `static` storage specifier must be initialized with a constant expression.

```
static int count=countValue();
```

a function call is not a constant expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
// wenn countValue ein Objekt zurückgibt

static int* count=0;  if(count==0)count=countValue();
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: He wrote the same code from @thatwiseguy in a one-liner