# Compilation error for defining static array with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

When I define an array like

```
double *first = (double *)malloc( N*N*sizeof( double ) );
```

There is not problem. But when I specify

```
static double *first = (double *)malloc( N*N*sizeof( double ) );
```

I get this error

```
error: initializer element is not constant
   10 |     static double *first = (double *)malloc( N*N*sizeof( double ) );
      |                            ^
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializer element is not a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902456/initializer-element-is-not-a-constant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may initialize objects with static storage duration with constant expressions. And an expression with a call of malloc is not a constant expression.

So you need for example initialize the pointer as a null pointer like for example

static double *first = NULL;

and then call the function malloc in a function

```
if ( first == NULL ) first = (double *)malloc( N*N*sizeof( double ) );
```